# How to redirect from login form to html file in @Controller passing by authenticate method in @RestController?

Tags: spring, security, authentication, redirect

Here is login form

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/api/v1/auth/login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When user submit login form it sends data to authenticate method in @RestController.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationRestControllerV1 {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserRepository  userRepository;
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public AuthenticationRestControllerV1(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestParam(name="username") String username, @RequestParam(name = "password") String password, HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn`t exist"));
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, user.getRole().name());

            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Authorization", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            response.addCookie(cookie);


            return new ResponseEntity<>(new JwtResponse(username, token),HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (AuthenticationException exception){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid email/password combination", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }

...
}
```

In SecurityConfig class method configure has successForwardUrl("/auth/success") which must redirect me to success page, but it doesn't. I also tried defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/success") and successHandler(successHandler). It just doesn`t work at all so it keeps me on authenticate method

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtConfigurer jwtConfigurer;

    private final JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtConfigurer jwtConfigurer, JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) {
        this.jwtConfigurer = jwtConfigurer;
        this.successHandler = successHandler;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().apply(jwtConfigurer)
         .and().formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll().successForwardUrl("/auth/success");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }



}
```

Here is @Controller which I use for getting my login page and success page

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(){
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/success")
    public String getSuccessPage(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because with your controller you bypass the original login from Spring Security so that config will not apply. You will return the response as is from the controller and completely bypass the Spring Security login configuration. So you either return a JWT token fro the login method OR you use Spring Security for the login and let that handle it. You cannot do 2 responses, return a token AND goto the default homepage.